# How to display ssh hostkey when using git?

Tags: ssh, security, git

I'd like to see hostkeys when using git via ssh, is there a way to enable git to show the keys. Visual or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Only way i've found is to override the ssh client, either via env var:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o visualHostkey=yes'
```

or via `~/.gitconfig` file

```
...
[core]
   pager = less -SR -x4
   sshCommand = "/usr/bin/ssh -o visualHostkey=yes"
...
```

For some reason, on my systems, the system wide ssh config is not applied when using git.

source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config